# Python: find_all is only working for some tags

Tags: python, web-scraping

the .findall function within bs4 is only working for some HTML tags. I am trying to scrape a website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://bitskins.com/'
page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')

# Gather the two lists
skin_list = page_content.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'panel-heading item-title'})
wear_box = page_content.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'text-muted text-center'})
```

When I print skin_list, it works successfully, however when I try to print the wear list, it prints an empty list.

I have tried one other thing:

```
wear_box = page_content.html.search("Wear: {float}")
```

This brought on an error stating that 'NoneType' object is not callable.

I am using Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://bitskins.com/'
page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')

skin_list = page_content.findAll('div', class_ = 'panel item-featured panel-default')

for skin in skin_list:
    name = skin.find("div", class_ = "panel-heading item-title")
    price = skin.find("span", class_ = "item-price hidden")
    discount = skin.find("span", class_ = "badge badge-info")
    wear = skin.find("span", class_ = "hidden unwrappable-float-pointer")
    
    print("name:", name.text)
    print("Price", price.text)
    print("Discount:", discount.text)

    # Choose which one you want
    for w in wear.text.split(","):
        print("Wear:", w)
```

You was trying to find the incorrect class. I added some other data which you can scrape for examples. Wear holds a few values which i outputted.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did I have the wrong class because I was looking through inspect element rather than the source code or was it just a mistake?

Comment: TBH when i was looking at the code via inspect i would have used what you did but when i outputted ```skin``` i found the value in the HTML in a different class so i used that class instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your line of code, you are searching for a tag with a class that has multiple values.

```
wear_box = page_content.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'text-muted text-center'})
```

On the page the only tag that fits is:

```
<div class="container text-center text-muted" style="padding-top: 17px;">
```

In BS4, when you are searching for attributes with multiple values, you either search for a single value eg:

```
wear_box = page_content.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'text-muted'})
```

Or you have to search for the exact list of vales eg:

```
wear_box = page_content.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'container text-center text-muted'})
```